# How to Create an Apex class that returns Account objects

Tags: apex, account, object

```
public class AccountUtils {
    public static void accountByState(){

            List<Account> myAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
    }
}
```

---

Why my code doesn't complete the challenge of trailhead? What is wrong?

the requirements are:

> Create an Apex class named AccountUtils and include a static method
>   named accountsByState that accepts a state abbreviation as a string
>   and returns a List of Account objects The method must return the ID
>   and name of all Account objects that match the BillingState for the
>   state abbreviation passed to the method

Answer (score 7):

> method named accountsByState that accepts a state abbreviation as a
>   string and returns a List of Account objects

You are not passing the parameter for state.

```
public static List<Account> accountsByState(String stateAbbr) {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState FROM Account WHERE BillingState=:stateAbbr];
}
```

Comment: it should be public static List<Account> accountsByState(String stateAbbr) {
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE BillingState=:stateAbbr];
}   Anyway, thank you a ot!1

Comment: There is no prob with extra field. Trailhead will accept it

Comment: Can you close the question if it solved. Pls go through https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work